# Js variables are undefined in IE after definition

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, cross-browser

I have javascript code that seems to be working on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari but fails to work in IE due to some variables being "undefined", yet if you look at my code you will see the variables being properly assigned a value. I feel like it has to do with the scope on where they are being defined but I don't want to break the code for the other browsers while trying to fix IE. This problem occurs in IE11 and IE8, but I haven't tested other versions of IE to verify.

```
function resizeCommentBox(obj,i){
    var lastItemCounter = obj[i].getElementsByTagName('tr').length - 1;
    var lastRow = obj[i].getElementsByTagName('tr')[lastItemCounter];
    var nextCommentBox = obj[i+1].getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

    console.log("lastRow.parentElement right outside the first conditional if(obj[i].offsetHeight < obj[i].scrollHeight): ");
    console.log(lastRow.parentElement);

    if(obj[i].offsetHeight < obj[i].scrollHeight){
        if( !(i+2 < obj.length) ){
            var template = document.getElementById('lastPageTemplate');
            var parentNode = template.parentNode;

            template.style.display="block";
            template.removeAttribute("id");

            parentNode.innerHTML = parentNode.innerHTML + template.outerHTML;
            parentNode.children[parentNode.children.length-1].setAttribute('id','lastPageTemplate');
            parentNode.children[parentNode.children.length-1].style.display="none";
            parentNode.children[parentNode.children.length-1].innerHTML = parentNode.children[parentNode.children.length-1].innerHTML;

        }

        console.log("lastRow.parentElement right outside the conditional if(lastRow.childElementCount > 0): ");
        console.log(lastRow.parentElement);
        if(lastRow.childElementCount > 0){
            nextCommentBox.innerHTML = lastRow.outerHTML + nextCommentBox.innerHTML;
            lastRow.parentElement.removeChild(lastRow);
        }
        else{
            lastRow.parentElement.removeChild(lastRow);
        }

            if(nextCommentBox.getElementsByTagName('tr')[nextCommentBox.getElementsByTagName('tr').length-1].innerHTML === ""){
                nextCommentBox.getElementsByTagName('tr')[nextCommentBox.getElementsByTagName('tr').length-1].parentElement.removeChild(nextCommentBox.getElementsByTagName('tr')[nextCommentBox.getElementsByTagName('tr').length-1]);
            }


        resizeCommentBox(obj,i);
    }
    else{
        try{
            var lastPageOnlyFooter = document.getElementsByClassName('keepOnLastPageOnly');
            for(var j = 0; j < lastPageOnlyFooter.length - 2; j++){
                lastPageOnlyFooter[j].parentElement.removeChild(lastPageOnlyFooter[j]);
            }
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

function checkCommenBox(elementCounter){

    var commentBoxCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('comments');
    resizeCommentBox(commentBoxCollection,elementCounter);
    commentBoxCollection[elementCounter].style.height = "auto";

    if(elementCounter < commentBoxCollection.length){
        checkCommenBox(elementCounter + 1);
    }

}

checkCommenBox(0);
```

The variables that keep failing are **lastRow** and **nextCommentBox** but they were defined at the beginning of the function. What I can't wrap around my head just yet is why it works on some many browsers but IE can't find the variables? Thanks you for your help and suggestions.

**Edited 08/31/15**
I took a few screenshots of the IE console to show the exact errors. As you can see, the *remove* method is not getting called because the reference is null. In this case, the reference called was the variable *lastRow*, which is a table-row element.

[image: IE11 javascript console error]

Checking my code, we find that the first *removeChild* function gets called on *lastRow.parentElement* which does exist:

```
lastRow.parentElement.removeChild(lastRow);
```

and doing console.logs outside the conditional and right before the removeChild function get called we see that the element pointer just vanishes.

[image: console.logs]

I switched the innerHTML on the table references for *appendChild* and *removeChild* functions, but this still fails on IE.

Comment: `elementCounter` is used as an index starting with zero. But you're comparing it against the length which is one based. When the last element is reached the if condition is still fulfilled and you're calling `checkCommenBox` with an undefined index (out of bounds). This happens in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue by doing a few logs into the console through out the script. It seems that the following line made the variable *lastRow* null:

```
parentNode.innerHTML = parentNode.innerHTML + template.outerHTML;
```

Before the previously mentioned line, lastRow had an element object as a value. After the line executes, the lastRow value becomes null (only on IE). To fix this, I had to change *parentNode.innerHTML* to use *appendChild* on *template.cloneNode(true)*.

```
parentNode.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));
```

Then I moved a few other functions around to make my code work like before.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to do here but using innerHTML and outerHTML attributes on IE browsers is not advised because it's only "almost" supported, especialy inside tables. See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html/ and try to dig this way.